# Only 1 array (irregular array)

Tags: php, arrays

http://prntscr.com/fl69px

Hi, how can I get the part shown in the picture? There are many arrays.

```
    Array
(
    [max] => 46.784
    [total] => 74.562
)
Array
(
    [0] => 6
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 18 Oct 2017  14:12
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2017-06-18T14:12:33+03:00
)
Array
(
    [0] => New Cup
)
```

**In short, I am not asking: New Cup**
There are 16 in total.

Comment: How did you generate that output? Is there a foreach involved? did you just print_r($whatever); ?

Comment: 1st: what have you tried? 2nd: you'd have to show the _whole_ array (that contains those arrays)

Comment: @Jeff {name} I just want to take the part

ss=> http://prntscr.com/fl6eoa

Comment: OK so whatever that variable is called... I will name it `$demo`... you need to do this.. `$demo->name;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want this array:

```
Array(
   [bet] => 3
   [featureEvent] => 0
   [bank] => 0
   [column] => 2
   [requiredBet] => 2
)
```

You can create a basic php [foreach-loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), which loops through your array and returns each key and value.

Currently we do not know how you created your array nor how the array name is, but lets assume that the array's name above is `$bets`

The foreach loop would look like this then:

```
foreach($bets as $betKey => $betValue)
{
    // do something ...
    // echo the values
    echo $betValues;
}
```